# Run a macro when any checkbox is hit in Word

Tags: vba, checkbox, ms-word

I'd like to fire generic code for an unknown number of checkboxes to change the formatting style of a line. I have multiple lines that lead with a checkbox and I want a check to set the line to normal and an uncheck to set the format to Heading 2.

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnEnter(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl)

If ContentControl.Checked = True Then
    Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal")
ElseIf contextcontrol.Checked = False Then
    Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2")
End If

End Sub
```

Checking a box sets the cursor on that line so I am hoping this strategy will work. I've never used vba in Word so I think I'm doing something wrong just in getting the code to fire?

Comment: Does the code run when you *leave* one content control and enter another? Content controls react the way form fields did: they don't react when you check/uncheck, they react when you leave (or enter) the content control... (Note: it's probably not going to do what you want it to do, as it is, but first we need to know the code is firing).

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The code isn't firing. Am I missing some setting that I don't know about?

Comment: In what code module does this reside? Is it in `ThisDocument` or somewhere else? And a simple way to check: put in a `MsgBox "Test"` line at the top. If you don't get a message you know nothing is triggering. And be sure to go from content control to content control, not from control to body text.

Comment: Yeah I had put it under Macros. I was able to get this working once I put it under ThisDocument. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a ContentControlOnEnter macro, which only tells you the state of the content control when you selected it, not what you might have changed it to. For the latter, you need a ContentControlOnExit macro - and to exit the content control after checking/unchecking the checkbox. Furthermore, you should check the content control's type, so that it doesn't throw and error if the content control is not a checkbox. For example:

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal CCtrl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
With CCtrl
  If .Type = wdContentControlCheckBox Then
    If .Checked = True Then
      .Range.Paragraphs.First.Style = wdStyleNormal
    Else
      .Range.Paragraphs.First.Style = wdStyleHeading2
    End If
  End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Your example code is throwing an error:
Compile Error:
Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name

Comment: @Reece - the sub was missing 'Cancel as Boolean'. Added.

Answer (score 0):

Missing an end if, and actually still needed to use on enter for this to work. Problem with code firing was because I put this under Modules > Macros instead of in the document. Correct code:

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnEnter(ByVal CCtrl As ContentControl)
With CCtrl
  If .Type = wdContentControlCheckBox Then
    If .Checked = True Then
      .Range.Paragraphs.First.Style = wdStyleNormal
    Else
      .Range.Paragraphs.First.Style = wdStyleHeading2
    End If
  End If
End With
End Sub
```